# Is a comma or "if" needed in this sentence

Tags: conditionals, sentence-starts, bare-conditional, reversed-conditional

> "X might not have been made had money been a priority"

We are discussing with friend about this sentence, which I had trouble understanding at first.

To me, it'd have been more idiomatic adding "if" or a comma in the middle like :

> "X might not have been made if money had been a priority"
>
> "X might not have been made, had money been a priority"

As we are both natively French, it may be me, trying to "frenchize" the sentence, am I ?

Comment: Both of your sentences below are correct.

Comment: But, is the first one correct, or does it require to be modified ?

Comment: You don't need comma with "if" in your sentence. You're right in using comma with "had" sentence. Both of them are correct.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1308 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95741  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/48819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protasis (the “iffy” part) of an [English conditional sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Inversion_in_condition_clauses) has never strictly required an *if* or an *unless*, no matter whether it should fall before the apodosis (the “thenny” part) or after it.  You just need a bit of inversion:

> Should anyone call, we shall notify you immediately.

Were it not so, I would have told you.

Comment: Thanks, the 'if' being 'out', now can this sentence be constructed without comma to seperate protasis and apodosis ?