# Why is the "were" placed ahead?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, conditionals, subject-verb-inversion

Loosely speaking, the mode is the highest bump, the median is where half the area is to the right and half is to the left, and the mean is where the histogram would balance, ***were** it a solid object cut out of a uniform block of metal*

[Here](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~stark/SticiGui/Text/location.htm#location) is the source.

Comment: It's creating a counterfactual (using the subjunctive, if you subscribe to the notion of a subjunctive in English). In other words: that *were* is acting like an *if it were*, because in reality, the histogram is *not* a solid object cut out of a uniform block of metal.

Comment: Related and probable duplicate of one or another of  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1308 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2631 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95741 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95943 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/177784 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/162357 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/233992  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/48819 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/32830

Comment: @tchrist Well-found. I'm VtC as a dupe of your first suggestion. Also, if you have some magic trick which allows you to explicitly add linebreaks in comments (and the fact those links appear each on their own line isn't just an accident or artifact of SE), you have to tell me what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is all in **subjunctive mood/conditional,** indicating the **hypothetical**:

*the mean is where the histogram **would** balance, **were** **it** a solid object cut out of a uniform block of metal*

meaning:

*the mean is where the histogram **would** balance, **if it [the histogram] were** a solid object cut out of a uniform block of metal*

or, less formal:

*the mean is where the histogram **would** balance, **if it [the histogram] would be** a solid object cut out of a uniform block of metal*

The "were it" subject-verb inversion devices replaces the "if" conditional construct.

"If it would be" is less formal, and some language boards consider it even incorrect/tolerated.