# Conditional sentence without conditional conjunctions, is that possible?

Tags: conditionals, subject-verb-inversion

Sometimes I hear sentences that sound conditional to me, just because of the (unassertive) ordering of the words. I don't know if I can come up with a proper example. Consider this:

> - *I'd be a lot better, had she stayed with me*.

And I guess it's equivalent to this conditional form:
*If she had stayed with me, I would have been a lot better*.

So, this is my question:
In what ways can you make a sentence conditional without using conditional conjunctions (if, unless, etc)? And what are their equivalent conditional forms?

Comment: Please search this site before posting. This is a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1308 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2631 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95741 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95943 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/177784 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/162357 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/233992 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/48819 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/32830 and countless many others.

Comment: Also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214687/what-does-be-it-mean-in-this-passage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a conditional clause using **"should" "had", "were"**, instead of using a conjunction.

> "Should any of the clauses contain a mistake, please advise us immediately" (If any of the clauses...)
>
> "Were I to seek revenge, it wouldn't make me feel any better." (If I were to seek...)
>
> "Had I known the circumstances, I wouldn't have criticized her." (If I had known...)