# Omission of if in a conditional phrase

Tags: prepositions, conditionals, literary-english

This is an excerpt from Kant's *Critique of Pure Reason*.

> It is, however, clear that even this apprehension of the manifold alone would bring forth no image and no connection of the impressions **were
> there not** a subjective ground for calling back a perception, from which
> the mind has passed on to another, to the succeeding ones, and **thus for** exhibiting entire series of perceptions, i.e., a reproductive faculty of imagination, which is then also merely empirical.

The above sentenced puzzled me because of the bold-faced part.

- Is *were there not a subjective ground* a literary form of *if it were not for a subjective ground*?
- Why is *thus for* used? I think *thus* should be used instead. I don't see how the preposition *for* can be appropriate here.

Comment: For starters, Kant wasn't writing in English. His *Kritik der reinen Vernunft* has some of the densest prose, even for works of philosophy, ever written in any language (my $0.02). The *were there not* construction is clearly subjunctive, and so is a conditional. The *thus for* construction is used as a culmination, much as we would use "and so" today.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Must conditional sentences begin with "if?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48819/must-conditional-sentences-begin-with-if) Though [tchrist's monumental answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214687/what-does-be-it-mean-in-this-passage/214713#214713) is more comprehensive. '(8) Another way of forming an English conditional is to ... employ inversion and use  either a subjunctive or modal:

Were it otherwise, you would learn of this immediately.'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, ***were there not*** is a an inverted conditional and means *if there were not* ("were" is subjunctive):

> Although conditional clauses are often called if-clauses, they don’t always include the word *if*! *In more formal situations*, we use a technique called ***inversion*** where we reverse the order of the subject and the verb. These clauses are known as ***inverted conditionals*** or sometimes *reduced conditionals*.
> Inverted second conditional if-clauses are often restricted to formal, written English. In second conditionals, inversion is used to rewrite if-clauses that contain the verb be. Use the structure ***were + subject***.
>
> - *Were this* my hotel, I would be ashamed! = If this were my hotel, … ([lingholia](https://english.lingolia.com/en/grammar/other-conjunctions-inversion))

Such examples

> are *unreal conditionals* because they are distanced due to irrealis. They therefore use ***the subjunctive and use "were"*** instead of "was" (though speakers may ignore this rule and use was anyway). ([teflpedia](https://teflpedia.com/Inverted_conditional))

---

As for your second query, the answer is no, you should not omit ***for*** as ***exhibiting*** is connected by the preposition ***for*** to *ground*, just as *calling back a perception* is. Think of your sentence in this way:

> If there were not a subjective *ground **for** calling back* a perception [...], and thus ***for** exhibiting* entire series of perceptions...

So two gerundial clauses modify ***ground***:

1. ***for** calling back* a perception
2. ***for** exhibiting* entire series of perceptions