# Would be possible were

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

The wheelbarrow is designed to distribute the weight of its load between the wheel and the operator, so enabling the convenient carriage of heavier and bulkier loads than ***would be possible were the weight carried entirely by the operator.***

Could anyone explain what's the meaning of"would be possible were the weight carried entirely by the operator." and the grammar?

Thanks!

Comment: Please search this site before posting. This is a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1308 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2631 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95741 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95943 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/177784 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/162357 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/233992 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/48819 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/32830 and countless many others.

Comment: You should also join our sister site for [ell.se].

Comment: '... carriage of heavier and bulkier loads than would be possible were the weight carried entirely by the operator' ≡ '... carriage of heavier and bulkier loads than would be possible if the weight were/was carried entirely by the operator' (where '≡' is used for semantically identical).